# SQL Server CE (.sdf) file structure

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce, file-structure

I'm currently trying to write my own SQL Server CE (`.sdf`) parser which should be able to open, parse and retrieve information from a database in the SQL Server CE format as well as reference it for future use.

The problem is, I haven't been able to find a single source which describes the format in which these tables are constructed/read (unlike, for example, SQLite which has tons of references available).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server CE is a commercial product published by Microsoft, and it's totally up to them whether or not they choose to publicly document their file format internals. There are documented API to deal with SQL Server CE - why do you feel the need to go *behind their back* and read the `.sdf` file directly?

Comment: Understood, still, if someone by chance happened to deal with the same problem and is willing to share their insight, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you planning to acheive?,you can get both data and metadata using either C++ and OLEDB or .NET and ADO.NET - and  I have wrapped getting and scriptin both with my SqlCeScripting .net library

Comment: I also have a number of command line tools to help you with this

Comment: @ErikEJ: I see that there are many tools, both GUI and programs, which help access the DB. However, this is not my goal. I need to understand the DB's structure from the inside out, in order to, among other things, retrieve data which might not be accessible through said tools

Comment: Still trying to understand your goal -  exactly what kind of data might that be?

Comment: @ErikEJ: Some data, such as deleted entries, are invisible in most viewers (judging from my experience with SQLite), in addition I would like to allow for a reference to each entry's physical offset from within the .sdf file, therefore, I need to write my own parser. To do this, I need to understand how the file is built

Comment: Ok, hope you are aware that the file contents change the moment you Query the database file

Comment: All the more reason to create my own parser...

Comment: Do you happen to have a description of the file structure?

Comment: If "intellectual curiosity" isn't enough: SQL CE is currently used as a data format for a variety of scientific and biomedical instruments. SQL CE is also EOL and doesn't receive any security updates. A third party / OSS implementation would help secure research/medical facilities and also preserve access to data.

Comment: @jnj16180340 FWIW, I have tools and libraries to extract contents from .sdf files